# Get instances during serializer validation in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am starting to work with the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for a mini-reddit project I already developed.

The problem is that I am stuck in this situation:

A `Minisub` is like a subreddit. It has, among others, a field named `managers` which is `ManyToMany` with `User`.

An `Ad` is an advertising which will be displayed on the minisub, and it has a field named `minisubs` which is `ManyToMany` with `Minisub`. It has also a `author` field, foreign key with `User`.

I would like to allow these managers to add some ads on their minisubs through a DRF API. It is actually working. But I want to check that they put in `minisubs` only minisubs where they are managers.

I found a way like that:

```python
class AdSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # ...

    def validate_minisubs(self, value):
        for m in value:
            if user not in m.managers.all():
                raise serializers.ValidationError("...")
        return value
```

My question is: How to get `user` ? I can't find a way to get the value  `Ad.author` (this field is set automatically in the serial data according to the user authentication). Maybe I don't find a way because there is no ways ? The place to do this is somewhere else ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You may get it out of the serializer this way:

```
class YourModelSeializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=YourModel
    
    def validate_myfield(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a job for the [permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions), if you are performing CRUD operations for inserting that into a database then u can have a permission class returns `True` if the user is a manager.

a permissions instance has access to the request which u can use to get the user and check if he is a manager:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Comment: The problem is that I don't want only to know that he is a manager, but that he is a manager of all the `MiniSub` in the field `minisubs` of the `Ad` he is trying to post.

Comment: can it not be derived from a query on the user object ?
once you are in the body of the custom permission class you're writing you are free to look up anything from the database in oder to arrive at the conclusion of `True` or `False`

Comment: Once in the permission I can access to all I need on the database, yes. But the thing is I have to deserialize data from the request, to check if what the user put in it is legit.
Anyway I finally found ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19147358/2595458) how to get user in `validate_minisubs` method by using  `self.context['request'].user`. Thanks for your time !